# Remove every white space between tags using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I'm trying to remove white space between tags so that childNodes only contain those tags nodes not the white space nodes too. Here's my code :

```
<li>            
    <label for="firstName"  class="mainLabel">First Name : </label>                                 
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"/>                                    
    <span>This must be filled</span>
</li>
```

And here's the JS code :

```
var parentHTML = firstName.parentNode.innerHTML;
parentHTML = parentHTML.replace(/>\n</g,"><");
firstName.parentNode.innerHTML = parentHTML;
```

But when i alert `parentHTML` i get the same old string.

Comment: In a regex, whitespace is not `\n`, it's `\s`.

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the whitespace on the client in JavaScript on DOM nodes that are already rendered (presumably)? The browser ignores this whitespace anyway.  If you want to send more compact HTML to the client you'll need alter it at the server level.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's (not, see after the rule) because strings are immutable, I think, and you're setting the innerHTML of the parent element to be the exact same string you retrieved from it earlier.

Instead, I'd suggest:

```
var firstname = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
    parentHTML = firstname.parentNode.innerHTML,
    newHTML = parentHTML.replace(/\>\s+\</g,'');
firstname.parentNode.innerHTML = newHTML;

console.log(parentHTML, newHTML, (parentHTML == newHTML));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wygnD/1/).

---

With regards to the comment from jfriend00 (below), it seems the regular expression was the problem, the `\n` didn't match the supplied pattern, that being the case, the following amendment satisfies teh requirements:

```
var firstname = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
    parentHTML = firstName.parentNode.innerHTML;
parentHTML = parentHTML.replace(/>\s+</g, "><");
firstName.parentNode.innerHTML = parentHTML;

console.log(firstname, parentHTML);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wygnD/3/).

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the string assignment in the OP's original JS code.  Strings are immutable, but `.replace()` returns a new string which can be assigned to `parentHTML` just like the OP was doing so whatever issue the OP's code had, it was not because of string immutability.

Comment: @jfriend00: ah? Well, thank you for the correction. Also, the problem? Apparently the regex pattern. I should've known to look there first, answer edited, updated and corrected. =/

Comment: The .replace(/>\s+</g, "><") option here seems to work in my eyes - see https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/gms6nt35/ (although note, it needs a trim to remove outer spaces too)

Answer (score 23):

For most cases, I recommend removing space from:

- Beginning of document
- End of document
- After `>` character
- Before `<` character

There are two cases I can think of where this will not do what you want, and these are the same two cases that impact the less aggressive solutions above.

- Empty space between `inline-block` elements is actually an intended or expected part of the layout. If this space is collapsed to zero characters, the implicit space between elements is removed. This can be avoided by changing my regex below to replace with a `" "`.
- My original answer has been updated to preserve whitespace in `<script>`, `<style>`, `<pre>`, or `<textarea>` tags. All of these except `<pre>` are CDATA which means the content is not HTML and are parsed until the closing tag is found, which means the regex is a complete solution. If a `<pre>` is nested or the `white-space` CSS property is used, this will not preserve your content.

The solution:

```
    collapsed = expanded.replace(/(<(pre|script|style|textarea)[^]+?<\/\2)|(^|>)\s+|\s+(?=<|$)/g, "$1$3");
```

Comment: This is the only one that works. The accepted answer does not behave nicely when the string contains double quotes.

Comment: absolutely the best answer! should be the chosen one.

Comment: Great answer, though it removes spaces before `<a>` tags as well, which is probably not intended

Comment: This works great. I was wanting to remove space before in a contenteditable element.

Comment: This also remove spaces from <strong> and <b> tags so "Some <strong>strong</strong> text" becomes "Some<strong>strong</strong>text" which is wrong @adam-leggett

Comment: Great regex!  While JavaScript supports the kinda weird `[^]+?`, AFAIK most regex libraries don't. The equivalent for eg. Python and PCRE is `.+?`, making the entire regex: `(<(pre|script|style|textarea).+?<\/\2)|(^|>)\s+|\s+(?=<|$)`

Comment: to keep the spaces that bound `<a>` tags, you can use the following regex: `(<(pre|script|style|textarea)[^]+?<\/\2)|(?<!\/a)(^|>)\s+|\s+(?=<|$)(?!<\/?a\s+[^>]*>)(?!<a>)`

Comment: as philk says, this fails - see https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/cvyuknm0/8/

Comment: Yes this fails, Please update your answer.

Answer (score 10):

only spaces:

```
parentHTML = parentHTML.replace( new RegExp( "\>[ ]+\<" , "g" ) , "><" );
```

new line, tabs and spaces:

```
parentHTML = parentHTML.replace( new RegExp( "\>[\s]+\<" , "g" ) , "><" );
```

https://regex101.com/r/sD7cT8/1

Comment: `\r\n` is more like it instead of `\n\t`

Comment: @vsync: sounds like an opinion and does not help any question on this page.

Answer (score 5):

Can you treat a html tag as a string in js? I guess it can be done.
try this!

```
s.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Nope, that would replace also spaces like in: `<span>Wanted     Spaces</span>`

Comment: Thank you , friend.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread because I was searching for a solution to eliminate gaps around divs caused by white space in HTML source, or line feeds in my case.

Before I realized that white space could cause these gaps, I was going nuts trying to get rid of them. I want to keep my HTML source formatted for readability, so compressing the code is not a good solution for me. Even if I handled it this way, it doesn't fix divs that are generated by Google and other vendors.

I started by creating the following function and calling it in body onload.

```
function Compress_Html() {
    //Remove whitespace between html tags to prevent gaps between divs.
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( /(^|>)\s+|\s+(?=<|$)/g, "$1" );
}
```

This seemed to work perfectly, but unfortunately, it breaks the Google search box I have in my footer.

After trying many variations of the regex pattern without success, I found this regex tester at http://www.regexpal.com/. I far as I can tell, the following pattern does what I need.

```
( /(^|>)[ \n\t]+/g, ">" )
```

That said, the function was still breaking the search box. So I ended up moving it into a jQuery document ready function. Now it's working and does not break the search box.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( /(^|>)[ \n\t]+/g, ">" );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please see my revised answer. You probably have a `<script>` tag that was being modified and your version of the regex happens to not be breaking it.