# How to remove white space between html tags using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML content inside a JavaScript variable:

```
var string="<tr>  <td> data 1 </td> <td> data 2 </td>   <td> data 3 </td></tr>";
```

I want to remove the white spaces between HTML tags only. The White space in column data must be remain same.

```
string.replace(/\n/g, "");
string.replace(/[\t ]+\</g, "<");
string.replace(/\>[\t ]+\</g, "><");
string.replace(/\>[\t ]+$/g, ">");
```

I tried the above code. But this is not worked. Some one please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are  you trying to remove the first and last space of your `var string=" data 1 data 2 data 3 "` so that it becomes `var string="data 1 data 2 data 3"`

Comment: Exactly what spaces do you want to remove? All spaces in the string in your example are between tags (at least between the first tag `<tr>` and the last tag `</tr>`). And *why*? You have probably made a wrong analysis of some problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove every white space between tags using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014441/remove-every-white-space-between-tags-using-javascript)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
string= string.replace(/>\s+</g,'><');
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a jQuery solution:

Use `.contents()` and `.filter()` to find all whitespace-only text nodes and remove() them, like this:

```js
var $e = $("<tr>  <td> data 1 </td> <td> data 2 </td>   <td> data 3 </td></tr>");
$e.contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType = Node.TEXT_NODE && /\S/.test(this.nodeValue) === false;
}).remove();
console.log($e.html());
// <td> data 1 </td><td> data 2 </td><td> data 3 </td>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check console!
```

The above example filters children of `tr`. However, it is also possible to check descendants or make complex decisions such as keep whitespace between inline elements but remove between block elements.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring < and > chars inside text nodes:

```
var string = "<p>lol</p>  <p>let's remove <span>spaces between tags</span> </p>";
var rexp = new RegExp(">[\t\s ]*<", "g");
var result = string.replace(rexp, "><");
```

js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4cfgnfrx/

with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/4cfgnfrx/1/