# Nunjucks precompile clean html

Tags: javascript, templates, gruntjs, nunjucks

I use Nunjucks percompiled template and I'd like to clean the template.js output from useless spaces and linebreak.

Compiled template keeps useless space and line break from original template:

```
"<form>\n        <div class=\"choices\">\n            <div class=\"choice\">\n"
```

Custom tags like [nunjucks-tag-spaceless](https://github.com/jbmoelker/nunjucks-tag-spaceless) do the regex stuff client side.
There is no way to do this during compile step to save size / time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use jlto library for your purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jlto

Comment: Nice ! Now I have to find a way to use this with grunt-nunjucks

Comment: If you use Grunt, then you can register custom task: https://codepen.io/dmitry_krekota/pen/qjPKwy

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter within the nunjucks realisation code that cleans up your html according to the logic/library you use and executes it after the realisation of the template as and when the filter is called.
For more details on how to, you can check the [Documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#custom-filters).
For the implementation of the filter to clean up html, you can go through this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014441/remove-every-white-space-between-tags-using-javascript).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Filters operate on a given variable, as I want to remove useless space of the templates, custom tags are more appropriate. But custom tags / filters are not executed during compilation but client side (which is normal). So I'm looking for a way to add logic during compilation but not on client side.

Comment: Go through this link once [Docs](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#configure) . Have you tried using the _trimBlocks_ and the _lstripBlocks_ parameters in nunjucks config ? These are usually false in the default state.

Comment: Yep, I tried trimBlocks and lstripBlocks but I guess it only removes spaces/newline on Nunjucks block / tags, not on html string template. Tanks anyway